# I have create custom shortcode in wordpress but it show error

Tags: php, wordpress

When I try to display a shortcode in pages it shows this 'Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response' error but the page gets updated and no error shows in the frontend. When I use the classic editor it works fine but issues with block editor.

Here its code

```
<?php
class EmailPluginfront {

    function __construct() {
        
        add_shortcode('email', array($this,'front_display'));  
        
    }  
function front_display() {
                   
echo '<h2 style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:30px">'.get_option('email_title_field').'</h2>';
}
}
$EmailPluginfront = new EmailPluginfront();
```

Comment: _"Here its code"_ - what is the _context_ of this? Where is this placed, in what situations does it execute? Where did you place the actual shortcode?

Comment: I just insert first line of code not full code. I have insert this shortcode in page.

Answer (score 0):

you need to return data at the end of your function. try using this in your shortcode function

```
ob_start();
echo("Hello there!"); // all your code here
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $output
```

Comment: Its working fine. Thanks for help

Comment: welcome. don't forget to give the useful tag to answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use 'return' instead of the 'echo'?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).